# Why Google Structure Data Tools is Showing SiteNavigationElement Twice?

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data, site-structure

I have submitted Site Navigation Element (Structure Data) through the plugin to my website. Plugin I am using is "Schema.org Settings List." While I have run the website in structre data testing tool, It is showing SiteNavigationElement and Organization as two items. What could be the reason behind this? Is that affect the google ranking?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have in your source code the JSON-LD snippet with the type "SiteNavigationElement" twice, the first beginning in the line 119, the second beginning in the line 163 - thats why Google recognizes it twice. This one:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
    "name": [
        "Tech News",
        "Gadgets",
        "Smartphone",
        "Tutorial Series",
        "Java Tutorials",
        "Digital Marketing Tutorials",
        "Tech",
        "Developers Guide",
        "How To?"
    ],
    "url": [
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/tech-news/",
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/gadgets/",
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/gadgets/smartphone/",
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/tutorial-series/",
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/tutorial-series/java-tutorials/",
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/tutorial-series/digital-marketing-tutorials/",
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/tech/",
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/tech/developers-guide/",
        "http://www.deepdigged.com/category/how-to/"
    ]
}
</script>
```

I guess it should be caused by misbehavior of your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This issue is also with the Organization markup. How to resolve it?

Comment: inspect, what does this plugin - i guess its on any way messy. There should be gazillion of plugins which add structured data to Wordpress without to mess the source code. I can't guide you to one certain plugin, but use recommendations on wordpress plugin repository and you are in butter

Comment: Shall I delete the old structure data and submit the new one? If so, how to find the structure data in website code. I am using wordpress CMS. In that am I able to edit that?

Comment: i guess if you delete the plugin, these messy structured data will disappear too

Comment: Hi Evgeniy, I was going though the plugin and found that I have checked both the option i.e. Output On :All Pages (In Header) and Homepage. Hence google has picked up like that. Evgeniy do you have any recommendation for this?

Comment: no - have not enough experience with WP. but there is a special site from Stack Overflow family - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/